# $T:X \to Y$ bounded linear map and $X$ separable implies $Y$ is separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $T:X \to Y$ be a bounded linear map between Banach spaces. Suppose that $X$ is separable.

Is it true that $Y$ has to be separable?

---

I think yes, since the map is continuous it takes the countable dense subset of $X$ to a countable dense subset of $Y$.

Comment: I presume you want $T$ to be onto?

Comment: Yes, let it be bijective.

Comment: Surjective is enough. Your last statement will then be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true in a more general setting. Let $f: X\to Y$ be a continuous map between two topological spaces and $Q \subset X$ a dense subset. Then $f(Q)$ is dense in $f(X)$.

To see this, let $y\in f(X)$. Then let $x\in X$ so that $f(x) = y$. Let $V \subset Y$ be open and $y\in V$. Then $U = f^{-1}(V)$ is open and contains $x$. As $Q$ is dense in $X$, there is $q\in Q$ so that $q\in U$. Thus $f(q) \in V\cap f(X)$. As $y, V$ are arbitrary, this shows that $f(Q)$ is dense in $f(X)$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know, is it also true for the property of reflexivity?

Comment: Yes, it's true. The answer will be a bit long to be written here, but the main observation is that if $T: X \to Y$ is a bounded bijective linear map between two Banach space, then so are $T^*$ and $T^{**}$. That $T^{**}$ is bijective would force the canoncial embedding $Y \to Y^{**}$ to be surjective.

Comment: Concerning reflexivity you can also argue with the weak* compactness of the closed unit balls. If $T:X\to Y$ is onto then the unit ball of $Y$ is contained in a multiple of $T(B_X)$ (by the open mapping theorem)  which is weakly compact. Hence $B_Y$ is relatively weakly compact and weakly closed, hence weakly compact.